# Non Maximized matlab GUI figure

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, maximize-window

Is there a way to create a GUI which starts as a maximized windows?
I've tried to add `set(gcf,'Units','normalized','Position',[0,0,1,1]);` at the end of my gui's `mygui_OpeningFcn()` function but the GUI is not maximized properly (see printscreen).

Setting the GUI properties at GUIDE to `Units-'normalized'` and `Position-[0,0,1,1]` didn't help either.

I've also tried to use the [Matlab File Exchange maximize function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10274-maximize-figure-windows) by adding `maximize(handle.figure1);` at the end of my gui's `mygui_OpeningFcn()` but it doesn't work either (same visual result - a GUI which is not entirely maximized).

Is there a way to make the Matlab GUI appear as a maximized figure when I launch it?
Why am I getting this strange visual behavior of the GUI?

[image: GUI not maximized properly]

Comment: set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize'));

Comment: set(gcf,'Units','normalized','Position',[0,0,1,1]);

Comment: if you use guide make sure your gui is resizeable. If it's complicated you will need to write your own resize function.

Comment: @kol - I've tried both ways and I get the exact same result as with the `maximize` function, a non maximized figure (see image).

Comment: @bdecaf - I've changed the GUI resize behavior to "proportional" via the "GUI options" and also change it to "other (use ResizeFcn)", but the result is the same. Maybe I can't maximize a GUI from the openingFcn within the GUI itself?

Comment: if I recall correctly there might be a resize property for every element. Did you check for your textbox? (i think the coordinates should then be `relative`)

Comment: @bdecaf - There's no resize property for the listbox I use within the GUI. When I run the GUI without any uicontrol in it I get the same result, a non maximized GUI.

Comment: Try this: f = get(gcf,'JavaFrame'); f.setMaximized(true);

Comment: Ok - wrong words, I checked. Set the `Units` of the listbox to `normalized`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Windows machine, I suggest you use the [`WindowAPI`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31437) submission from FEX. It directly calls [Windows API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) functions (using a MEX file), thus allowing far more advanced control of figures than just minimize and maximize:

```
hFig = figure('Menubar','none');
WindowAPI(hFig,'Maximize')
```